# How can I achieve Joining/Processing Data in an Event Based Architecture in Apache Beam on Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I was having a use case where I have to join a data using a unique key and wait for the events to process the bagged data at the end when it recognizes a specific field in the data. The code should also join as soon as it gets that specific key and write to those fields to bigquery in python.

**My Main Blocker is I want my code to wait for the last event to come in the series of events (that can be recognized by a field in the data) and only then the processing of data happens.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, assuming you are storing this data in biqquery, once all data is loaded, you can write a table function on the raw data to check if the field in the data is what you want to trigger further data processing? so flow is like this, 1) apache beam -> BigQuery 2) step 1 done, Use table function to check the field value, if exists, trigger using remote functions or even eventrc ? let me know what you think

Comment: Hi there again, does this https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#valuestate help ? the approach is more like to use counters to check for a key and then start processing as soon as counter>some value

Comment: Hi @Mihir Sharma Could you elaborate more on your requirements?

Comment: I'll do that with an example,  just imagine you have a event in your data column that is "START" for a user named "XYZ". I want to collect all event of the user "XYZ" and wait until the "STOP" event comes in my data somewhere as "Event_Name", when this happens I want to join the data for this specific user and write it in bigquery.  I hope I'm clearer this time.

Comment: It is possible to write something, that collects incoming data until a user-defined trigger is activated. However, given the massive parallelism provided by beam, it is not guaranteed that your input will be in order (see second to last paragraph in the [docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#state-and-timers)). So it could be you see "STOP" even though there are still events coming in for that user...